# Python: how do i sort the list inside the dictionary

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, average

I want to sort `score_list` by the values from `class1`.

I'm able to sort `score_list` alphabetically by simply sorting the keys, but I can't figure out how to sort the list numerically from largest to smallest.

Additionally, I want `score_list` to only store the last 3 inputs, and, if it is possible, I would like to find the average for each students last 3 scores.

```
enter code here:




score_list = []
class1 = {}
what_class = input ("what class would you like?")
if what_class == ("1") :
    print("class1 results")
    student_name =input("name?")
    score = input("score?")
    choose = input("do you want to entre another student? y,n")
    while choose == "y":
        student_name =input("name?")
        score = input("score?")
        score_list.append(score)
        choose = input("do you want to entre another score? y,n")
        class1.setdefault(student_name,score_list)
        if choose == "n":
            sorted_names = sorted(class1.keys())
            print(class1)

class1_items = class1.items()
print (type(class1_items))

for i in class1_items:
    print (i)
```

if someone can help me i would be very thankful it
thank you for the help

[]a better look on the objectives:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn5RO.png)

```
enter code here
import heapq
from collections import deque
print("alphabetical(type:A),highest to lowest(type:B),Average(type:C)")
student_name = input("ENTER NAME")
result_type = input ("WHICH TYPE OF RESULTS WOULD YOU LIKE?")
which_class = input ("which class?")

if result_type == ("A") or result_type == ("a"):
    print("alphabetical order(type:A)")


if result_type == ("B") or result_type == ("b"):
    print("results in highest to lowest.")
    score_list = deque(maxlen=3)
    scores = input("Please enter your score.")
    choose = input("do you want to entre another score? y,n")
    while choose != "n":
        scores = input("Please enter your score.")
        choose = input("do you want to entre another score? y,n")
        score_list.append(scores)
        if choose != "y" :
            print(score_list)
            print((student_name)+"'s:"+"lowest to largest"+str(heapq.nsmallest(3, score_list)))
            print((student_name)+"'s:"+"largest to lowest"+str(heapq.nlargest(3, score_list)))

if result_type == ("C") or result_type == ("c"):
    print("results in average order.")
    score_list = deque(maxlen=3)
    scores = input("Please enter your score.")
    choose = input("do you want to entre another score? y,n")
    while choose != "n":
        scores = input("Please enter the  scores.")
        choose = input("do you want to entre another score? y,n")
        score_list.append(int(scores))
        #print(len(score_list))
        #print(sum(score_list))
        total = (int(sum(score_list)))
        length = (int(len(score_list)))
        average= (total)/(length)
        if choose != "y" :
            print(student_name+"'s "+"average score:"+str(average))
           #print("average: " +str(average))
```

this is how i have improved it i still cant figure out the alphabetically sort part.

[the objectives to help you know what i am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3biid.png)

Answer (score 0):

---

Update, you should be capable to just paste and run following code
but still, you needs to wrap the input loop by your self, which means, connect interfaces / function call

```
import json
class Quize():
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = {}

    def createClass(self, class_name):
        self.db[class_name] = {}

    def createUser(self, class_name, user_name):
        self.db[class_name][user_name] = []

    def addScore(self, class_name, user_name, score):
        self.db[class_name][user_name].append(score)
        self.db[class_name][user_name] = self.db[class_name][user_name][-3:]

    def printClass(self, class_name, order = None):
        if not order:
            print json.dumps(self.db[class_name], indent=4)
        else:
            to_sort = self.db[class_name]
            print 'order', order
            if order == 'by highest':
                print sorted([ [max(to_sort[name]), name] for name in to_sort ], cmp = lambda x, y : y[0] - x[0])
            if order == 'by lowest':
                print sorted([ [min(to_sort[name]), name] for name in to_sort ], cmp = lambda x, y : x[0] - y[0])
            if order == 'by average':
                print sorted([ [sum(to_sort[name]) / len(to_sort[name]), name] for name in to_sort ], 
                                cmp = lambda x, y : y[0] - x[0])
            if order == 'by name':
                print sorted([ [to_sort[name], name] for name in to_sort ], cmp = lambda x, y : x[1] > y[1])
    def printUser(self, class_name, user_name):
        print json.dumps(self.db[class_name][user_name], indent=4)

    def dump(self):
        print json.dumps(self.db, indent = 4)

ins = Quize()
ins.createClass('0302')
ins.createUser('0302', 'jack')
ins.createUser('0302', 'tom')

ins.addScore('0302', 'jack', 99)
ins.addScore('0302', 'jack', 92)
ins.addScore('0302', 'tom', 99)
ins.addScore('0302', 'tom', 92)
ins.addScore('0302', 'tom', 19)
ins.addScore('0302', 'tom', 29)
ins.addScore('0302', 'tom', 66)

ins.printClass('0302', 'by highest')
ins.printClass('0302', 'by lowest')
ins.printClass('0302', 'by average')
ins.printClass('0302', 'by name')

ins.printUser('0302', 'tom')
ins.printUser('0302', 'jack')
ins.printClass('0302')

ins.addScore('0302', 'jack', 11)
ins.addScore('0302', 'jack', 37)
ins.addScore('0302', 'tom', 80)
ins.addScore('0302', 'tom', 72)

ins.printClass('0302', 'by highest')
ins.printClass('0302', 'by lowest')
ins.printClass('0302', 'by average')
ins.printClass('0302', 'by name')

ins.printUser('0302', 'tom')
ins.printUser('0302', 'jack')
ins.printClass('0302')
```

Comment: that doesnt seem to work: this are my tasks 
• Make a log for the user based on their performance.
• The system should store the last three scores for each student.
• Output the results of the quiz for a particular class, sorted:
• In alphabetical order with each students highest score for the test
• By the highest score, highest to lowest
• By the average score, highest to lowest
• Allow the teacher to select which class group to look at and which field to use when sorting the output data.

Comment: He's not storing multiple test scores per student, from what I can gather. edit: ok so I guess he is judging by his comments sorry!

Comment: oh man, you are just too lazy, python is  convenient enough to express ideas

Comment: i might do the homework for you if you still did not figure this out by your own in 36 hours, :) , type on phone is difficult

Comment: jack i have been trying to figure it out for 2 months now a while now but i cant seem to figure out its just hard i am very new to coding sorry for looking like a nob haha and thank you for your help so far it

Comment: when you say connect interfaces to function calls  do you mean make a input section for each variable you have used in the functions.

Comment: also can is it possible to do this by pickle, which I am very well at managing and understanding. also does json work on python?

Comment: when i say connect interfaces to function, i means to wrap these function call at your input loop, just like the raw_input you've write, so user are free to whether input the data or try to select / print in some order, and yes, json works fine on python, i just use json.dumps to control format, it's easy to json.loads for something, i believe you have the python docs at hand, don't you?

Comment: i've wrote the back end data representation for you, so you have to carefully use it, to show a list for user input just like some old day DOS or some menu programs, i think you are not meant to wrote some PyQt graphic tools, it's even further for you to get their,

Comment: i dont understand what your telling me to do to make it work sorry

Comment: if you could just finish it as well it would be good because my dead line this Monday and if not i totally understand but i should just try figuring  it out but i am a bit short on time and i have been trying for the last 2 month again thank you for your help.

Comment: hey jack man i really need your help man idk what to do anymore to make it work.

Comment: you should at least read 'how to ask question the smart way', lazy questioner are never welcomed, if you spend two month on this small quest, how many hours have you spend on the manual, despite the fact that you are undergraduates or not familiar with object oriented programming, I've already show you the module, of course I'm not here to educate you, but if you can just copy and paste, It's meaningless for you to hand in the homework

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of issues here, but I'll go over a few.  You need to make sure you convert your input to an int(), otherwise you'll be doing math on strings and that's gonna cause a problem.  Second, and most important, the dictionaries are not ordered, so you're never going to get the same last 3 entries.

You can use list comprehension to fetch the grades and sort them, which the first thing after else: does, because the input order is irrelevant. For the next two, you can't use the dictionary values, you must refer to the list that you're using to keep track of the input grades.

```
grade_list = []
class1 = {}
if input('what class would you like? ') == '1':
    while True:
            student_name = input('name? ')
            score = int(input('score? ')) # must convert input to int
            grade_list.append(score)
            class1[student_name] = score
            if input('do you want to enter another student? ') == 'y':
                pass
            else:
                # fetch grades
                grades = [v for k, v in class1.items()]
                # print highest to lowest
                print(sorted(grades, reverse=True))
                # print last 3 grades
                print(grade_list[-3:])
                # print avg of last 3 grades
                print(sum(grade_list[-3:]) / 3)
                break
```

Output

```
what class would you like? 1
name? Abby
score? 11
do you want to enter another student? y
name? Bobby
score? 22
do you want to enter another student? y
name? Charles
score? 33
do you want to enter another student? y
name? Damon
score? 44
do you want to enter another student? n
[44, 33, 22, 11]
[22, 33, 44]
33.0
```

Comment: I have no idea if you're trying to store multiple test grades per student, but if you are hopefully this provides a good foundation for how to approach the problem.

Comment: i need a the name of all the students and their last 3 scores not just the highest 3 scores out of all the students

Comment: Then I suggest you get crackin.  There are more than enough comments on here to get you started.